# Cannot Delete Registry Entry even with Admin Rights

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I have the following registry entry `SOFTWARE\\mysoftware\\"` in the `localmachine`

There are several subfolders and values within it.I just want to remove `SOFTWARE\\myspftware\\`

So i use

```
 Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree("SOFTWARE\\mysoftware\\");
```

in a program with admin rights. I keep getting the error

`Cannot delete a subkey tree because the subkey does not exist.`

even though the key exists.

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile, due to the final backslash. Does your *actual* code have the trailing backslash (escaped or not)? I would try it without - the key doesn't logically end in a backslash; that's just the separator.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have 2 backslahes.Please see the update.It was a typo.

Comment: Wow, declined my edit, then did the exact edit...

Comment: @hellyale lol .. i did not notice your edit.sorry.

Comment: Its the exact edit word for word. I doubt that coincidence highly.

Comment: @hellyale i did NOT click the reject button.I saw the first comment before i  saw your edit and went ahead and edited.dont be childish.

Comment: What ever you say boss... based on the question id check your code to make sure it isn't just a typo, for instance SOFTWARE\\myspftware\ won't delete anything because that key doesn't exist.

Comment: @hellyale i typed wrong in the question.In the code its correct.

Comment: @JonSkeet I removed the backslash and put in `SOFTWARE\\mysoftware` it does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
RegistryKey mykey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true);
mykey.DeleteSubKeyTree("mysoftware");
mykey.Close();
```

I think the `true`in `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true)` is the magic part.

Comment: I need to remove the whole entry `SOFTWARE\\test`

Comment: i will try and get back.